# My edit was rejected and replaced with a questionable one

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

Today i had this edit suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11473636 rejected on this post [Create and initialize bidimensional array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734412/create-and-initialize-bidimensional-array-in-angularjs) with the reason "This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed."

Despite low general quality of the question, the issue I had seen was that the user asked a general javascript question as if it was about angular and i have replaced any reference to angular with "javascript" (but still pointing out that it was inside an angular application).
When i checked the revision history to see what was actually needed to be changed according to the the user who rejected my edit I found out that he replaced the references to "angular" with "AngularJS" and "2D" with "bidimensional".

I still think my edit is more useful than the current edit, since the question is not really about angular but it's a general javascript question which happens to be on code from an angular controller

Comment: *The user asked a general javascript question as if it was about angular.* They use `$scope`, so it is about Angular. Scopes are specific enough to that technology for the tag to be legitimate I believe.

Comment: the issue is about general javascript which just happened to be inside an angular application's code. if there was `var $scope = {};` inside the question's code it wouldn't have changed anything about the issue and the question wouldn't have been about angular anymore in any way

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but that `var` statement is not present, and the use of `$scope` does refer to the bridge between controller and view. Modification of `$scope` can have side effects that would not occur with a plain `$scope` variable, that's why I believe you should at least have left the `[angularjs]` tag around.

Comment: I see your point but I don't really agree on this. I might be wrong but i think a tag has to be used whenever someone looking for informations/issue about a certain topic might find a question useful. If i was looking for how to do something while using angular and found this question i wouldn't actually find anything useful that would improve my knowledge about angular or about how to do things in angular

Comment: ...but this could just be me being wrong about when to use a tag

Comment: The name of the language implementation is JavaScript and the name of the library is AngularJS, if the version is 1, and Angular, if the version is 2.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan this is something we all agree on i suppose. The issue is that i think my suggestion was more important that the one made by the user who rejected mine. This is not a question that addresses an angular issue, just a javascript issue that happens to be inside an angular's controller